# Is there a nullglob option for ksh(korn shell)?

Tags: wildcards, ksh

I want to run a for loop, is there a way to do a nullglob in the korn shell like in other shells?

```
for file in docs*.txt; do
```

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16956/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184133/117549

Comment: Yes, as seen in the answers to the questions marked as duplicates. Prefix the pattern with `~(N)`.

Comment: I don't have a timeline for what versions of ksh that's true for, but is the right direction.

Comment: @JeffSchaller When `ksh` is mentioned without any other qualifier, I'm assuming `ksh93`.

Comment: @Kusalananda No, it's ksh *83*

Comment: 83? Do you mean 88? On what Unix?

Comment: @Kusalananda my colleague told me it's Linux. But I suspect he is wrong. I will recheck that

Comment: @Roland Do consider updating your question with the type of Unix you're using, the version of `ksh` that is in use, and whether `~(N)docs*.txt` works as you want it to or not. Unfortunately there are a number of various `ksh` shells (`ksh88`, `ksh93`, `pdksh` and `mksh`), and they work slightly differently compared to each other.

Comment: @Roland see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199900/how-can-i-safely-get-the-version-of-ksh for help in determining the ksh version.